# Sum function in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

Hi I m trying sum function in solr

*val*:"sum(kcmeta/bookmark/count,10.00)"

itis giving error:

```
<lst name="error">
  <str name="msg">undefined field: "kcmeta"</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
```

My field name is "kcmeta/bookmark/count"

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: seems issue with the / in the field name? any reason you are using / can you change it to _ and check.

Comment: no @jayendra its a predefined field name. I cant change it.

Comment: see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3996

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the special char you have in the name like this:

```
val:"sum(kcmeta\/bookmark\/count,10.00)"
```

This should not happen but it seems there is a bug, so the escaping should work around the bug:  issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3996

Comment: have already tried this. its not working. we are using solr 4.

Comment: yes then it works. problem is with "/". But i cant ignore it. because these are predefined fields.

Comment: can you add fields? maybe you can make a copyfield and use the other instead. Nasty but if nobody finds a solution...